# Random width div filling the container width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have to fill the `width` of my container with the `div` inside it. But the `width` of each `div` is selected randomly between 3 possible width in jQuery.

There is a JsFiddle, it would be easier to understand what I mean after that.
https://jsfiddle.net/2bcqj3dj/1/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var classes = ["col-sm-4", "col-sm-3", "col-sm-2"];

  $("#container .item").each(function() {
    $(this).addClass(classes[~~(Math.random() * classes.length)]);
  });
});
```

```css
#container {}

.item {
  background-color: #000;
  height: 250px;
  min-width: 16.666666666%;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  color: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid #FFF;
}

.item.col-sm-2 {
  width: 16.6666666%;
}

.item.col-sm-3 {
  width: 25%;
}

.item.col-sm-4 {
  width: 33.33333333%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">b</div>
  <div class="item">c</div>
  <div class="item">d</div>
  <div class="item">e</div>
  <div class="item">f</div>
  <div class="item">g</div>
  <div class="item">h</div>
  <div class="item">i</div>
  <div class="item">j</div>
  <div class="item">k</div>
</div>
```

The goal is to perfectly fill the container `width`, I mean, I don't want to see any margin to the right of my content.

Note that I don't know the numbers of final items in my container since they are create in PHP.

Comment: Please always include all relevant code within the question. User's shouldn't have to go off-site to answer, let alone understand, what you're asking.

Comment: How is it possible to perfectly fill the container, if you have only three widths available?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Sure sorry for that.

Comment: @FrancoScarpa, That is the question ahah. Seriously, I don't know and that's why I asked. Is there any solution to do this with totally random width (without the 3 width i have).

Comment: You won't be able to handle the case of 1 or 2 items, the rest you can manage, but need some logic that helps your random function so it isn't that random, I assume you will create a new row when you reach 100% in width?

Comment: To reach exactly 100% filled rows you need to limit you random function so it only has valid options to pick from when you get closer to the end.
for example with 9 items you only have 4 possible ways to get even filled rows, 1/3 * 9 = 3 rows, 1/6 * 6 + 1/3 * 3 = 2 rows, 1/6 * 4 + 1/4 * 4 + 1/3 * 1 = 2 rows, 1/6 * 2 + 1/4 * 4 + 1/3 * 2 = 2 rows

Answer (score 0):

You can create sets of valid combinations to fill one row, and then depending on how many items you get pick random sets until your quota is filled.

Combinations to get one row filled:

```
items | 1/6 | 1/4 | 1/3
  1      -     -     -
  2      -     -     -
  3                  3
  4            4
  4      1     2     1
  5      4           1
  6      6
```